# Drop DB via SQSH

Tags: sql-server

I want to drop a remote sql server DB using SQSH. I've tried two ways;

the first one is to set the DB offline given that the auto change is off.

```
sqsh -h -S databaseHost -D master -U USER -P PASS -C "ALTER DATABASE ${TARGETDB} set OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; DROP DATABASE ${TARGETDB}"
```

This results

```
Error: 615, Severity: 21, State: 1. Could not find database ID 9356, name '9356'
```

The second way

```
sqsh -h -S databaseHost -D master -U USER -P PASS -C  "ALTER DATABASE ${TARGETDB} set SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; DROP DATABASE ; DROP DATABASE ${TARGETDB}"
```

This works fine but if no one else is connecting/trying to connect to the DB, if so then it results

```
The database is in single-user mode, and a user is currently connected to it.
```

The second way should work fine because I set it to single-user and drop it in the same connection, or it's supposed to be the same connection, any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Are you sure this question is for SQL Server and not for Sybase?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple issues with the way you are trying to `DROP ..` the database.

1. The SQSH command prompt doesn't seem to be able to drop an OFFLINE database.
2. When set to SINGLE_USER a database can be used by any user. You might have connections to the database between switching the database to SINGLE_USER mode and dropping the database. Or the SQSH command prompt has a handle on the database.

To overcome these issues you might want to perform the following:

1. Set database offline.
2. Set database online.
3. Set database into restricted user mode.
4. Drop database.

In summary this would look like this:

```
ALTER DATABASE <database> SET OFFLINE WITH ROLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
ALTER DATABASE <database> SET ONLINE
GO
ALTER DATABASE <database> SET RESTRICTED_USER
GO
DROP DATABASE <database> 
GO
```

Now `sqsh` is a replacement for Sybase's `isql` command prompt executable. As such there may be reasons why this will not work with SQL Server (as your tag is suggesting).